# Displaying warning to IE6-8 users once per session

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've looked around and I couldn't find an exact solution, but if one does exist, I apologise.

Now, the problem I'm having is displaying a div once per session to users of the older versions of Internet Explorer i.e. < IE9.

Here is the code I quickly put together but it doesn't seem to be working, could someone please tell me what's wrong with it? Am I doing it all wrong?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
    /* Set initial cookie after entire page has loaded */
    document.cookie="messageseen=true";

    /*********** 
       This cookie won't exist initially, but when the if statement below checks
       for the message seen cookie, the clear message cookie will also be set,
       this is so on subsequent page-loads, it won't take 5 seconds for the the
       message to disappear. 
    ***********/
    if (document.cookie == "clearmessage") {
       $('.ie-message').hide(); // hide message without delate
    }

    /*********** 
       After 5 seconds, check for the messageseen cookie, if it exists, set the
       clearmessage cookie and hide .ie-message. On all subsequent page-loads,
       the message will be hidden immediately without the delay.
    ***********/
    setTimeout(function (){
       if (document.cookie == "messageseen") {
          document.cookie="clearmessage=true";
          $('.ie-message').hide(); // hide message if cookie is set
       }
    }, 5000); // delay the hiding of the message for 5 seconds
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.cookie) gets *all* cookies in `key=value` pairs.

Comment: You cannot access cookies like that. try `if (document.cookie.indexOf("clearmessage")!=-1)` or get yourself https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: In addition to proper parsing of the cookie string, you will probably also want to set a path to "/" so the cookie can be seen from all pages on your site not just the one page it was set from.

Answer (score 0):

Using

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
    /* Set initial cookie after entire page has loaded */
    $.cookie("messageseen",true);

    /*********** 
       This cookie won't exist initially, but when the if statement below checks
       for the message seen cookie, the clear message cookie will also be set,
       this is so on subsequent page-loads, it won't take 5 seconds for the the
       message to disappear. 
    ***********/
    $('.ie-message').toggle(!$.cookie("clearmessage")); // hide message without delate

    /*********** 
       After 5 seconds, check for the messageseen cookie, if it exists, set the
       clearmessage cookie and hide .ie-message. On all subsequent page-loads,
       the message will be hidden immediately without the delay.
    ***********/
    setTimeout(function (){
       if ($.cookie("messageseen")) {
          $.cookie("clearmessage",true);
          $('.ie-message').toggle(0); // hide message if cookie is set
       }
    }, 5000); // delay the hiding of the message for 5 seconds
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hello, I added jquery-cookie to the page and the updated script that you have posted but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried it without the Internet Explorer conditional tags in Chrome as well as with the conditional tags in Internet Explorer 6 via BrowserStack. Now, the cookies aren't being set at all.

Comment: I'll have a look. I am just outof bed and I do not have windows at home, so give me a few hours. I want to simplify the script. Only one cookie needs to be set. Not sure what browser stack does to cookies

Answer (score 0):

If you only going to have that one cookie you can do something like that:
(note that i'm hiding the div inline to prevent blinking on slow page load)

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div class"ie-message" style="display:none;">IE MESSAGE</div>
<script>
(function($){
  if ( document.cookie == "" ) {
  // show message
  $('.ie-message').show();
  // add cookie;
  document.cookie = "seen=true";
}
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just tried your method but it didn't work, the cookie isn't set.

Comment: Either your browser settings are not allowing cookies, or are you working locally or on a server? Last the example i typed did not include any expiration date, you might need to look into that as well. Try including the library @mplungjan shared on his answer

Comment: I've tested it using MAMP, uploaded to my external server and tried it in Chrome without the conditional tags and then tried it with and without conditional tags in IE6 and 7 on Win XP using BrowserStack.

Comment: Yes, I load JQuery before the script and yes I'm getting errors. http://i.imgur.com/YTwUl3u.png

Comment: Yeah it seems that the cookie is not formatted correctly, do some google search to find how to append the expiration date, or simply use the jquery plugin from @mplungjan